# SWIFT: how to print with a For in Loop with dictionary in dictionary

Tags: swift, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I was wondering how I could print just the names only or various if possible. At this point I have a simple for in Loop printing the entire collection.

```
var players: [[String: Any]] = [

    ["Name": "Joe Smith",
     "Height": 42,
     "Experience": true,
     "Guardians": "Jime and Jan Smith",
     "Team": ""],

    ["Name": "Jill Tanner",
     "Height": 36,
     "Experience": true,
     "Guardians": "Clara Tanner",
     "Team": ""],

    ["Name": "Bill Bon",
     "Height": 43,
     "Experience": true,
     "Guardians": "Sara and Jenny Bon",
     "Team": ""],
]

for teamSelector in players {
    print(players)
}
```

Comment: Your title says about looping a dictionary in a dictionary, but it is actually a dictionary contained in an array.

Comment: Thx for correcting me totiG. Just started with Swift. This is a project of my online course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following using your example, but updated to get the name:

```
for teamSelector in players {
    print(teamSelector["Name"])
}
```

You can also use map to print all the names:

```
print(players.map { $0["Name"] })
```

Another option is to loop over each of the players and cast the name as a string and then display the name. Using flatMap here ensures all names are strings.

```
for name in players.flatMap({ $0["Name"] as? String }) {
    print(name)
}
```

Comment: Thank you totiG. This is much appreciated!

Comment: The first example is the most simplified and understood syntax for me to use! Thx!

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

For print the values:

```
players.values.forEach { (value) in
            print(value)
        }
```

For print the "name" (that called 'keys'):

```
players.keys.forEach { (key) in
            print(key)
        }
```

In other style you can write it like:

```
for key in players.keys{
            print("The key is: \(key)")
            print("The value is: \(players[key])")
        }
```

Comment: There's nothing ugly about `for ... in` loops. In fact, in quite a lot of cases, I would *encourage* their use over `forEach` – as `forEach` loops don't allow for pattern matching or `where` clauses, you cannot (easily) break out of them & they're really not much shorter than a `for ... in`. People just tend to like `forEach(_:)` loops because they're shiny and use closures.

Comment: Hamish, thank you for your feedback! I just started Swift and this is my first project for my online course. Since your overall suggestions are very helpful - some of the examples I am not too familiar with but will study them.

Comment: Dekel Maman, thank you as well for providing examples! I just started Swift and this is part of my first project for my online course. Some of the syntax I am not too familiar with - I will study it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this would print only the names:

players.foreach() { print($0["Name"])

Comment: Thx PEEJWEEJ! I am not too familiar with some of the syntax such as the empty paranthesis and the use of $0 but I'll google that :)